# How do I automatically share external USB drives over the network?

Tags: macos, networking, hard-drive, osx-server

I used to have an old G5 tower running OS X 10.5 (Leopard) which I was using as a fileserver. In this tower I had a USB dock connected where I could plug in 2.5 inch drives from my archive and then access them over the network by connecting to the G5.

Last week I upgraded my "fileserver" and I am running OS X Mountain Lion Server on a regular Mac Pro tower. When I connect to my new fileserver via Finder I am only able to see the local hard drives but none of the external ones. I can add a share-point for the external drives but that is not very practical since I am always connecting different drives from the archive.

So what I would like to have is that when I plug in an external drive to my file server it shows up in the network shares without me having to create a share-point for every different drive I connect.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sharing `/Volumes/`

Go to the Sharing system preferences, click the `+` under Shared Folders. You can toggle hidden items with `Command+Shift+.`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately its not working for me. I have shared Volumes successfully but all I can see is a symbolic link to the system drive and nothing else. Do you know what the problem might be? On the other OS X lions workstations we have it seems to be by default that one can see all the drives attached to it.